# How can I programmatically fill out a web form with JAVA?

Tags: java, cookies, webforms, automation

I just need help filling out a web form programmatically with [java](/questions/tagged/java). I use Apache HttpClient 4.0.1. The form looks like this:
[image: Web Form Example]

HTML code of it looks like this:

```
DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd" <ol>Some tags</ol> <ol> 
Do not show the ticket (pre)view when the user first comes to the "New Ticket" page.

Wait until they hit preview. Ticket Box (ticket fields along with description)</ol> <ol>form action="/tracenvir/newticket" method="post" id="propertyform"--div--input type="hidden" name="__FORM_TOKEN" value="dff95a43ddec5a653627d2c0"</ol>

<ol>input type="text" id="field-summary" name="field_summary" size="70"</ol> <ol>textarea id="field-description" name="field_description" class="wikitext" rows="10" cols="68"</ol> <ol>input type="hidden" name="field_status" value="new" </ol> <ol>

      input type="submit" name="preview" value="Preview" </ol> <ol>

      input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create ticket"</ol>
```

And there are many other tags. Here's my java code:

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

    client.getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.COOKIE_POLICY, CookiePolicy.BEST_MATCH);

    client.setCookieStore(new BasicCookieStore());


    //**LOG IN**//


    //System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "/home/rauch/NetBeansProjects/jssecacerts");

    HttpGet login = new HttpGet("http://localhost:8000/tracenvir/login");

    client.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY,

            new UsernamePasswordCredentials("rauch", "qwerty"));
```

And then correctly Login... I get 200 OK and everything is well.

```
    //**POST NewTicket**

    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8000/tracenvir/newticket");

    List<NameValuePair> formparams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("__FORM_TOKEN", cookies.get(1).getValue()));

        formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("field_summary", "Someerror"));

        formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("field_descryption","AnyDescryption"));

        formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("field_type", "defect"));

        formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("field_priority", "major"));

        formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("field_milestone", "milestone3"));

        formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("field_component", "comp2"));

        formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("field_version", "1.0"));

        formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("field_keywords", ""));

        formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("field_cc", ""));

        formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("field_owner", "java server"));

        formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("field_status", "new"));

        formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("submit", "Create ticket"));

    try {

        UrlEncodedFormEntity entity;

        entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(formparams, "UTF-8");

        post.setEntity(entity);

        post.addHeader("Referer","http://localhost:8000/tracenvir/newticket");


        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);


        System.out.println("Create ticket: "+response.getStatusLine());


        client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();


    } catch(UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {

        ex.printStackTrace();

    } catch(IOException ex) {

        ex.printStackTrace();

    }
```

And Server responses  **HTTP/1.0 200 OK** . But this "New Ticket" doesn't appear at ViewTickets web page. If I do the same with a normal web browser, fill out fields and push Button "Create ticket" everything is OK and I can see this NewTicket at ViewTickets web page. This is what the browser generates request:

```
__FORM_TOKEN=0856803edd721d8b9592231d&field_summary=fuckingStatusField&field_description=mmm+status&field_type=defect&field_priority=major&field_milestone=milestone1&field_component=component1&field_version=2.0&field_keywords=&field_cc=&field_owner=ubuntu-server&field_status=new&submit=Create+ticket)</ol>
```

Why does it not work? By default I shouldn't use this:

```
formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("__FORM_TOKEN", cookies.get(1).getValue()));
```

DefaultHttpClient must do this, but it doesn't. If I comment this statement, Server responses  **HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request**

What should I do to correctly fill out this form?

I tryed to imitate Browser: Firstly GET /newticket page, And then generate POST request with Headers like Browser generates.....But programatically I have 200 OK from Server, but this NewTicket doesn't appear at list of Tickets.

Comment: This question makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: well, it does, although very poorly stated

Comment: It had 1 line of incomprehensible text when I wrotye the above comment. Its now _alot_ longer!

Comment: it would be easier if you debug the whole thing, check with firebug, log messages on both sides, etc

Comment: Your post is messed up. I tried to edit and fix it, but it seems worse. Did you copypaste it from some other forum or so? Please don't do that. Copypaste unchanged from your source code (assuming that it is already *well intented*), select the code here again and then get it formatted by either pressing the code (010101) button or Ctrl+K. You can also get it formatted by manually putting 4 spaces in front of it.

Comment: Yeah, you are wright. Firstly I wtote normall message, but when I pushed "Post your question" button, my browser - Opera_10.10(64 bit) isn't correctly work. I just copyed my message to *.txt file and pasted from it to FireFox wich is seems to correctly work with stackoverflow.

Comment: You really need to use a "page object" design pattern.  your example is perfect for it.   get hints from "LoadableComponent".

Answer (score 4):

Apache Http Components (or the old HttpClient), Selenium, HtmlUnit - depends on your exact case

Comment: I see.
I have wrote - Just wait a moment...Why did you firstly write, but not read my ask?

Comment: Why did you submit the question without having it finished? This makes no sense as well. If you want a preview, just look below the message box.

Comment: Ok...I apologise for my stupid actions.
May be you can help me giving useful advice?

Comment: 'just wait a moment' was from the incomprehensible part of the question :)

Comment: "Apache Http Components", no HttpClient anymore.

Comment: there is still, but I'll add http components

Answer (score 4):

1. Use a packet capture utility such as Wireshark to monitor the http requests.
2. Compare what the browser is sending to what your code is sending.
3. Modify your code accordingly.

Comment: +1 - Right approach, though it would be better if the OP could get his web server / container to do the capture; e.g. using RequestDumperValve in Tomcat.